# Change column sizes by clicking in angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript, bootstrap-4

i have this page that has two buttons  divided By two clo-md-6 :
i want when i click in the button the first button become col-md-9 and the other  col-md-3 and the same for the inverse

i don t know how to do it in angular
[image]

This is my HTML :

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <!-- $("#btn1").parentElement.parentElement.className= "col-3"-->
        <!--------------------THE FIRST BUTTON----------------------------->
        <div class="col-xl-6" [class.col-xl-9]="isclicked">
            <div class="card">
                <button type="button" id="btn1" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="AfficherRecherche()">Agent professionnelle</button>
                <div class="card-body" *ngIf="isclicked">
                    <h4 class="header-title mt-0 mb-4">Agent Professionnelle</h4>
                    <aw-wizard>
                        <aw-wizard-step class="sw-main sw-theme-default">
                            <form [formGroup]="searchForm">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-12">
                                        <div class="form-group row mb-3">
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" (keyup)="searchTerm.next($event)" formControlName="search" placeholder="Rechercher ..." (input)="search()" [(ngModel)]="searchText" />
                                            <div *ngIf="loading">
                                                <p class="search-message">Searching</p>
                                                <div class="lds-ellipsis">
                                                    <!-- -------------------------------THE SEOND BUTTON------------------------------------------------------------------ -->
                                                    <div class="col-xl-6" [class.col-xl-3]="isclicked">
                                                        <div class="card">
                                                            <div class="btn-group">
                                                                <button id="btn2" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="AfficherAgentpar()">Agent Partculier</button>
                                                            </div>
```

this is my component :

```
 AfficherRecherche() {
    this.isclicked = !this.isclicked;
  }

  AfficherAgentpar() {
    this.agentparclick = !this.agentparclick;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should trigger classes on click. So for example:

In your TS file declare a variable with a boolean:

```
public resize: boolean;
```

In your HTML you have 2 divs and a button:

```
<div class="clo-md-6" [class.col-md-9]="resize"></div>
<div class="clo-md-6" [class.col-md-3]="resize"></div>
<button (click)="resize != resize">Trigger me</button>
```

What happens is the following: When the button gets clicked it changes the value of our `resize` boolean. Since this is false by default, it'll trigger to true. When `resize` is true, the first div will be assigned the `col-md-9` class, and the second div will be assigned the `col-md-3` class. If you click the button again, the divs will go back to being 50/50.

Comment: it didn t work i updated my post to see my html  this is what happen when i click the button :  <div _ngcontent-bmy-c9="" class="col-xl-6 col-xl-3"> <div _ngcontent-bmy-c9="" class="col-xl-6 col-xl-3">